# Seed data vs class hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a browser based RPG and I am trying to figure out the best way to store "seed" data, ie. data like locations, monsters and items, that are standard entities of the game.

Would it be best to store this in a "def self.items.." hash in which i keep all the different items, or should I put them in a database and seed them? If I should seed them, what is the best way to accomplish this, just fill up the seed.rb files with 200-300 different instances or keep them in other files?

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely hate cluttered seed files. Admittedly, it's a personal preference and not a right or wrong.

Here's what I did in my app at work to handle the significant volume of seed data we are required to use:

```
# Folder Structure
db
  schema.rb
  seeds.rb
  seeds/
    01_organization.rb
    02_real_estate_industry.rb
    03_click_types.rb
    ...
```

My seeds.rb file:

```
# All seeds are broken out into ordinally names files inside the db/seeds/* directory.
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '**/*.rb')].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

A sample seed file in the seeds/ folder:

```
organizations = Organization.all
Organization.create(
  {
    name: 'CompanyName',
    blurb: 'Hi. I am a blurb.',
    city: 'Some City',
    state: 'ST',
    web: 'http://www.somewebsite.com',
    phone: '1-000-555-1212'
  }
) if organizations.empty?
```

This has the effect of loading our seed files in the desired order (using 01_ then 02_, etc.). It also breaks up our seeds into logical groupings and organizes them in such a way that, for our team, we can more easily manage them.